# Ant using waitfor to run task until a porperty is set

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I'm running the following code:

```
 <target name="_queryForRunningJobs">
   <ac:trycatch property="NODE_Reboot.failed">
     <try>

       <queryForRunningJob action="queryForRunningJob" jenkinsbaseURL="${targetRSSURL}" property="isRunningJobs" ignoreJobsLike="${ignore.jobs.like}"/>
       <echo message="${isRunningJobs}"/>
       <fail message="There is at least one job currently running on ${targetRSSURL}">
         <condition>
           <isset property="isRunningJobs"/>
         </condition>
       </fail>
     </try>

     <catch>
       <echo message="NODE_Reboot EXCEPTION: ${NODE_Reboot.failed}"/>
       <property name="reboot.failed.execution" value="${NODE_Reboot.failed"/>  
       <ac:var name="isRunningJobs" unset="true"/>
     </catch>

     <finally>
     </finally>
  </ac:trycatch>
</target>
```

I'd like to change the try block so that queryForRunningJob happens every hour for say 6 hours until isRunningJobs is NOT set, if it is I unset it and wait an hour.

I've been trying to use waitFor, but I can't get it to run the custom task and also check that the property is not set.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a good task for a python or shell script... not so much for ant.

Comment: Waitfor should support condition...

Comment: it does support condition, but not in this nested case. I eventually just fixed this so that the query happens after other tests targets execute in other scripts (every 4-5 hours) and the query happens once and fails frequently, but it works for what i needed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not` and `isset` conditions in the `waitfor` to make sure the variable is unset.

As for checking whether `isRunningJobs` is set or not, you can create a separate thread using `parallel`.